# Android DropBox API-Link with DropBox Fails(DBRoulette)

Tags: java, android, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

When I try access dropbox API with DBRoulette, example application from Dropbox API, using Android,
I get the following two messages in the simulator:
Link to Dropbox(I click it) then
-Unfortunately browser has stopped.
I've got an APP_KEY, SECRET_KEY from dropbox, my manifest file is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity
    android:name=".DBRoulette"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>

<activity
  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
  <intent-filter>
    <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
    <data android:scheme="db-XXXXXXX" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My main file is DBRoulette, identical to the example app:

```
com.dropbox.android.sample;
public class DBRoulette extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "DBRoulette";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                      Your app-specific settings.                      //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
// Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
// ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
// Obfuscation is good.
final static private String APP_KEY = "xxxxxx";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "xxxx";
....
```

I am using all jars suggested:dropbox-api, http-mime, json-simple, and android 4.4 as the version.
Why can't I access dropbox? is it because the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because it ran on the simulator not on the phone.
Used it on the phone, no problems.